# Get Configurable Product Price When Using Lowest Price Simple Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, simple-product

I am showing the Lowest price simple product price on the configurable product using [the](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) extension (organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple).

When I echo `$product->getPrice()` for the configurable product ID is will show the lowest price simple product price.

The actual price of the configurable product is £99.99, how do I get this value?

I need to compare the configurable price and the lowest price simple.

can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it.

To get attribute value outside of product page I used:

```
$product->getData('price')
```

Maybe I should have looked harder :?